# What's the different between "!=" and "=" in Jade template engine when used for assigning a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I just started learning NodeJS (and JS, so sorry if it's a silly question).

Today I read an example in ExpressJS documentation, about how to use Jade template engine. Here is the lines:

```
html
  head
    title!= title
body
  h1!= message
```

While I also saw some others are using `title=title` (**!** is omitted).

In traditional programming language, this two are totally different. But it seems fine to use both here, the output is the same.

I also tried:

```
meta(charset='utf-8')
```

and

```
meta(charset!='utf-8')
```

They make no difference at all, at least from what I saw. I cannot find anything neither on google nor the official Jade documentation.

Can anyone tell me the internal difference (if there is) between the two please, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escaping. From someone's [template syntax docs](http://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/#escaping),

Given:

```
{ "name": "Hello <em>World</em>" }
```

Escaped:

```
li= name
<li>Hello &lt;em&gt;World&lt;/em&gt;</li>
```

Raw (e.g., "surprise!"):

```
li!= name
<li>Hello <em>World</em></li>
```

There's also the inline escaping, http://jade-lang.com/reference/interpolation/

Answer (score 1):

### Buffered Code

Buffered code starts with `=` and outputs the result of evaluating the JavaScript expression in the template. For security, it is first HTML escaped:

Jade:

```
p = 'This code is <escaped>!'
```

Compiled html:

```
<p>This code is &lt;escaped&gt;!</p>
```

### Unescaped Buffered Code

Unescaped buffered code starts with `!=` and outputs the result of evaluating the JavaScript expression in the template. This does not do any escaping, so is not safe for user input:

Jade:

```
p!= 'This code is' + ' <strong>not</strong> escaped!'
```

Compiled html:

```
<p>This code is <strong>not</strong> escaped!</p>
```

Source: http://jade-lang.com/reference/code/